# jQuery sortable table inside a div with overflow auto extends beyond div

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using jQuery UI sortable to sort a table.  The problem is when the table is inside a div with overflow:auto and a set width, the dragged row appears outside of the bounds of that scrolling div.

How do I make the row, or a clone, respect the overflow?
[Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tv50bn97/1/)

Here is the code in the fiddle:

HTML:

```
<div id="theDiv">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>One1</td>
        <td>Two</td>
        <td>Three</td>
        <td>Four</td>
        <td>Five</td>
        <td>One2</td>
        <td>Two</td>
        <td>Three</td>
        <td>Four</td>
        <td>Five</td>
        <td>One2</td>
        <td>Two</td>
        <td>Three</td>
        <td>Four</td>
        <td>Five</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>One2</td>
        <td>Two</td>
        <td>Three</td>
        <td>Four</td>
        <td>Five</td>
        <td>One2</td>
        <td>Two</td>
        <td>Three</td>
        <td>Four</td>
        <td>Five</td>
        <td>One2</td>
        <td>Two</td>
        <td>Three</td>
        <td>Four</td>
        <td>Five</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>One3</td>
        <td>Two</td>
        <td>Three</td>
        <td>Four</td>
        <td>Five</td>
        <td>One2</td>
        <td>Two</td>
        <td>Three</td>
        <td>Four</td>
        <td>Five</td>
        <td>One2</td>
        <td>Two</td>
        <td>Three</td>
        <td>Four</td>
        <td>Five</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>One4</td>
        <td>Two</td>
        <td>Three</td>
        <td>Four</td>
        <td>Five</td>
        <td>One2</td>
        <td>Two</td>
        <td>Three</td>
        <td>Four</td>
        <td>Five</td>
        <td>One2</td>
        <td>Two</td>
        <td>Three</td>
        <td>Four</td>
        <td>Five</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  width: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

td {
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
  $("tbody").sortable();
  $("tbody").disableSelection();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'containment' option to do this.

```
$("tbody").sortable({containment: "#theDiv"});
```

See http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-containment for more info.

Comment: I don't think containment is at all related to the problem.  Adding that option did not fix the problem.